# Why does reloading user daemons fail?

Tags: systemd, sudo

If I do:

```
sudo systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

It fails with:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Being the "sudo" necessary, as this belongs to a package installation.

Answer (score 0):

With `sudo`, you're running `systemctl --user` as root... but if root is not logged in at the time, there is no active per-user D-Bus instance for root.

Only actual logged-in users have a user-specific D-Bus instance running. Using `su` or `sudo` may not necessarily be fully equivalent to a real login in this particular sense. If your Linux distribution has the `loginctl` command, use it without any parameters to see which users have active sessions (in the sense that they have an active per-user D-Bus instance).

The `--global` option is only meaningful with `systemctl enable` or `systemctl disable`.

If you want to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` on all currently active users' sessions, you might want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for reloaduser in $(loginctl --no-legend list-users | awk '{print $2;}')
do
    sudo -u $reloaduser systemctl --user daemon-reload
done
```

Comment: That throws "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory".

Comment: Using "sudo -E" it works.